# Permission denied when mounting volume with podman in fedora

Tags: docker, linux, security, podman

I use a docker-compose.yml file to boot my containers. My container mount to a external volume which targets a directory inside my user profile (postgres database files).
However, after switching from Windows (using Docker for Windows) to Fedora (and also to Podman), i cannot mount my volume any more because of permission issues.
When i add the `:Z` Flag at the end of my mount, then everything works. However: The big problem is, that i cannot add the flag because my colleagues who still are on Windows cannot use this docker-compose.yml file any more because docker complains about the `:Z` flag.

Is there a OS level solution for this?

**What i've tried so far:**
these commands (while i am in the project directory (which is the same directory, my mount points into)
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t svirt_sandbox_file_t "$(pwd)(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -Rv "$(pwd)"

**background info:**
I am a software developer. the docker-compose.yml is committed to my git repo. the postgres database files are part of the git project (however, they are in the .gitignore file). I've checked out the project into a directory inside my user profile. therefore the docker-compose.yml as well as the target directory of my mountpoint are both in separate directories inside my user profile.

Any ideas?